# How to go to a new JSF page from a PrimeFaces commandbutton enabled from ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have created a UI with below code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Zip Files loading</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />

</h:head>
<h:body styleClass="bImage">
    <center>
        <b><font color="Yellow" size="36px"> Welcome</font> </b>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <p:graphicImage  library="images" name="filetrans.gif" id="img" style="display: block"></p:graphicImage>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <h:form>   
            <p:growl id="growl" />
            <p:commandButton value="Upload zip files" type="button" onclick="PF('pbAjax').start();
                    PF('startButton2').disable();
                    PF('cancelButton').enable();
                    show(PF('img'));" widgetVar="startButton2" />
            &#160;&#160;&#160;
            <p:commandButton disabled="true" value="Cancel" widgetVar="cancelButton" actionListener="#{progressBarView.cancel}" oncomplete="PF('pbAjax').cancel();PF('startButton2').enable();PF('cancelButton').disable();" />
            <br /><br />
            <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{progressBarView.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false" style="width:400px">
                <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{progressBarView.onComplete}" update="growl" oncomplete="PF('startButton2').enable(); PF('btnReport').enable();hide(PF('img'));"/>
            </p:progressBar>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <p:commandButton disabled="true" widgetVar="btnReport" value="View Report" action="Report"/>

        </h:form>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(id) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        function hide(id) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.style.display = 'block';

        }
    </script>
</h:body>
```

In the above code, I want to go to the next JSF page `Report.xhtml` on click of button `View Report` (the last button). This button is initially disabled and when the progress bar is completed then it is enabled. 
I try clicking on the button to the next page but I'm unable to.

On the other hand, if I don't control the disability of the button from ajax(i.e do not enable and disable it) I'm able to go to the next JSF page easily.

Comment: The code you have in the question had a lot of js issues when i copied to my workspace.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar Its not showing any issues to me.. The UI is visible on browser. What are the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your `View Report` command button is disabled by default (as you used `disabled=true`), enabling it form Javascript using `PF('btnReport').enable()` will only make the button change CSS and make it look like enabled, but in fact your button is disabled.
To Make this work, create a variable at your managed bean.Like:

```
boolean disableReportBtn  = true;
public void onComplete(){
//your existing logic
disableReportBtn   = false;
}
```

And at you XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton id="reportBtnId" disabled="#{progressBarView.disableReportBtn}" widgetVar="btnReport" value="View Report" action="Report"/>
```

Update the button after progress bar complete:

```
 <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{progressBarView.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false" style="width:400px">
    <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{progressBarView.onComplete}" update="growl reportBtnId" oncomplete="PF('startButton2').enable();hide(PF('img'));"/>
 </p:progressBar>
```

Comment: the button is not enabling even after progress is complete. :(